# How to get number of password retries in eToken SafeNet by IAIK PKCS#11

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11, iaik-jce, safenet

I use Java and IAIK to read eToken info.

```
Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance("PKCS11.dll");
    pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
    Slot[] slotsWithToken = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT);
    log.info("number of slots: {}", slotsWithToken.length);
    Token[] tokens = new Token[slotsWithToken.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < slotsWithToken.length; i++) {
        Session session = null;
        TokenInfo tokenInfo = null;
        try {
            tokens[i] = slotsWithToken[i].getToken();
            tokenInfo = tokens[i].getTokenInfo();
```

[image]

This is the information I took out:

Information returned only 'Security Officer PIN final Try' true of false.
However I need to know how many times I have to re-enter the password so that I can notify the user. I've searched online but there's no positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard pkcs#11 calls, there is no way to get the actual number of (possible) retries.

For the user's pin, there are the flags:

- CKF_USER_PIN_COUNT_LOW and
- CKF_USER_PIN_FINAL_TRY

For the SO pin, there are the flags:

- CKF_SO_PIN_COUNT_LOW and
- CKF_SO_PIN_FINAL_TRY

Which you can check on the TokenInfo class. So you can 'only' display a warning on the final try. Please also refer to the [pkcs#11 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.pdf).

However, as Alexander mentioned in another answer there might be a vendor defined api for this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also find it really impossible

Answer (score 2):

There are exist Supplementary API (SAPI) for eToken located inside of `eTSAPI.dll`.

The method you need to call is:

```
CK_RV SAPI_GetSlotInfo(
  CK_SLOT_ID slotId, 
  CK_ATTRIBUTE_PTR pTemplate,
  CK_ULONG ulCount);
```

You must query this four attributes (values are DWORD types):

```
#define CKA_SAPI_RETRY_USER                  0x80001110
#define CKA_SAPI_RETRY_SO                    0x80001111
#define CKA_SAPI_RETRY_USER_MAX              0x80001112
#define CKA_SAPI_RETRY_SO_MAX                0x80001113
```

Documentation [link](https://manualzz.com/viewer_next/web/manual?file=%2F%2Fs3p.manualzz.com%2Fstore%2Fdata%2F030290742.pdf%3Fk%3DAwAAAX-Y9iTeAAACWMFtVUqiYNKFB4Qk6VB3A-rbNkuH&img=%2F%2Fs3.manualzz.com%2Fstore%2Fdata%2F030290742_1-4ab56389a23b2d188c33df4092954a9f#page=92&zoom=auto,104,684).

C# prototype can look like

```
[DllImport("eTSAPI.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern UInt32 SAPI_GetSlotInfo(UInt32 slotId, [In, Out] CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template, UInt32 count);
```

Have a look how [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop) implement [C_GetAttributeValue](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/47e4e17af64cc9cd46460022e056c49505fbe5fd/src/Pkcs11Interop/LowLevelAPI40/Delegates.cs#L106) method.

Comment: thanks for your help, Can you give me a document for reference?

Comment: Documents is not so easy. I'll check.

Comment: Thank you so much. I send email to IAIK to ask and waiting for a response.

Comment: I have been googled and found it. Now I can share it with you.

Comment: Thank you for giving me direction but i can't access to eTSAPI.dll by java. I searched google but nothing. how to use eTSAPI.dll in java or C#. Thank you very much

Comment: This is possible to call for extension from C#. I'll check.

Comment: I am anxiously waiting for your reply. I think if c# can do it, java can do it too

Comment: Check my new edits to answer.